# How to approach hiding an element if class is found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out jquery still and in my attempts I'm trying to figure out not only how to use various thing but why, I haven't tested any of this so not even sure it works (and apologize ahead of time if my code is terrible/crap); however, with jquery it seems like there is an unlimited number of ways to approach everything, so what's the best method? what's a better method if not listed? Why?

This code is meant to show/hide an element if `.active` class is present.

```
if($('.active').length > 0){
   $('.more').attr('hidden').animate({opacity: "1"}, 200);
   /* ...or should I use
     $('.more').prop('hidden');
   */
}
```

or something to this effect?

```
if($('.active').length > 0){
   $('.more).is(':hidden');
}
if($('.active').length === 0);
   $('.more').not(':hidden');
}
```

or is just adding/removing class more appropriate?

```
if($('.active').length > 0){
   $('.more).addClass('hidden').fadeOut('fast');
}
if($('.active').length === 0);
   $('.more').removeClass('hidden').fadeIn('fast');
}
```

or should item just be shown/hidden like this?

```
if($('.active').length > 0){
   $('.more).hide('fast');
}
if($('.active').length === 0);
   $('.more').show('fast');
}
```

say the HTML is something like this:

```
<p class="more">More something or another</p> <!-- hidden if .active exists -->
<ul>
    <li class="active"></li> <!-- active added dynamically if selected -->
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

The code executing the `.active` toggle is working and below:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.vl-toggle-link').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle(function(){
         var offsetTop = $(this).parent().offset().top;
         $('body,html').stop().animate({scrollTop: offsetTop-20 });
      }).parent('li').toggleClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active').children('.content').slideUp();
    });
 )};
```

Comment: How about `if ($('.active').length){ $('.more').hide() }`

Comment: Where is the class that you're testing for found? A parent, a child, a sibling? What's the HTML? If there's *one* element with that class should *all* elements of the other class be hidden/shown? Though, given the cases you've provided, I'd suggest: `$('.more').toggle($('.active').length > 0);`

Comment: You're markup and other business logic will usually decide which "style" or "pattern" to use... the flexibility is awesome, no?

Comment: _"with jquery it seems like there is an unlimited number of ways to approach everything"_ Yeah, with jQuery there's pretty much always more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @DavidThomas the element `.more` is separate. The idea is to add more of a description on what to do if nothing is selected in an accordion. so it's neither a parent, child, or sibling of the accordion, it's a separate description area. The HTML is near the bottom of the post.

Comment: @jibsales & j08691 I know, it's great! But while learning I am striving to know which methods are preferred and why. Better to learn the correct way than fix it later (at least I hope)

Comment: @darcher There isn't a "correct" way here, they are all legit. Biggest thing to be conscious of in jQuery is querying the DOM – especially when looping – as this is the quickest way to crashing your browser or delivering a poor UX

Comment: @jibsales that's what I'm beginning to figure out, which makes absorbing jquery slightly more difficult but in the end much more robust and adaptive. Really appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `toggleClass`:

```
$('.more').toggleClass('hidden', !!$('.active').length))
```

Then add the animations via CSS transitions:

```
.more { -webkit-transition:opacity 500ms; opacity:1 }
.hidden { opacity:0 }
```

There are many ways to "do things", but in the end it’s a matter of writing performant, "understandable" code and keeping in line with browser support etc. The jQuery API does have some great methods that are also self-explanatory in it‘s naming conventions.

Working with classes and CSS transitions allows you to separate logic from presentation nicely, and it’s easy for other co-workers to hook into the CSS without being bothered by inline styling.

Comment: This would definitely simplify things, and I love the idea of doing transitions with css as I'm more familiar with it. I've been scouring the jquery API site as of late and it is full of great information. But as always there is a greater source of knowledge in collaboration, hence this post. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Two things to remember: transition are not supported by every browser http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions; when an element is set to opacity: 0 it will block user from clicking anything below it.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto luckily transitions degrade "gracefully."

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best solution is to use classes since they are supported by every browser.

The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects, use it if you want a smooth transition.

With `$(...).hide()` the matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

The hidden attribute is supported in all major browsers, except some vs of Internet Explorer. The hidden attribute must not be used to hide content that could legitimately be shown in another presentation. For example, it is incorrect to use hidden to hide panels in a tabbed dialog, because the tabbed interface is merely a kind of overflow presentation — one could equally well just show all the form controls in one big page with a scrollbar. It is similarly incorrect to use this attribute to hide content just from one presentation — if something is marked hidden, it is hidden from all presentations, including, for instance, screen readers.

Attributes vs. Properties

The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

Comment: I’m confused, you recommend classes but the entire answer is about a "hidden attribute"?

Comment: Well ... I could go all day about classes but I don't think it's necessary. If you wanna know more about it you can start here: http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/