# Text input hidden, need to make it visible when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Me and a couple other guys are trying to create a simple blackjack game using javascript for school, but we are having trouble getting it to work correctly. Right now, when new game is clicked, it generates the numbers just fine and the Dealer 2 input is hidden like it should be. However, we are having trouble getting it to where when the Stand button is clicked, the Dealer 2 input becomes visible. Is there a clean way to go about this?

The Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Blackjack</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            background: url("cards.jpg");
        }
        section {
            width: 600px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: #007929;
            padding: 15px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: solid #000 2px;
        }
        header {
            width: 550px;
            height: 50px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            background: url("cards.jpg");
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: solid #000 1px;
        }
        h1 {
            line-height: 10px;
        }
        div {
            width: 400px;
            height: 300px;
            float: left;
        }
        aside {
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            float: right;
        }
        table {
            width: 400px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .cards {
            background-color: #63dd8d;
            border: solid #000 1px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 14pt;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .button {
            background-color: #009900;
            width: 150px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: solid #000 1px;
            clear: both;
            margin: bottom: 15px;
         }
    </style>
    <script>
        var dealer1;
        var dealer2;
        var player;

        function dealer() {
            dealer1 = document.getElementById("dealer1").value =       Math.random()*11 + 1;
            document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.floor(dealer1);

            dealer2 = document.getElementById("dealer2").value = Math.random()*11 + 1;
            dealer2 = Math.floor(dealer2);
            document.getElementById("dealer2").value = "Hidden";

            player = document.getElementById("player").value = Math.random()*21 + 2;
            document.getElementById("player").value = Math.floor(player);
        }
        function stand() {

        }
        function dealCard() {

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <header>
        <h1>Simple Blackjack</h1>
    </header>
    <form>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dealer Cards:</td>
                    <td><input id="dealer1" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer1" size="5" disabled="true" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="dealer2" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer2" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Your Card Total:</td>
                    <td><input id="player" class="cards" type="text" name="player" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <aside>
            <input type="button" name="deal" value="Deal Card" onclick="dealCard()" class="button" /><br><br>
            <input type="button" name="stand" value="Stand" onclick="stand()" class="button" /><br><br>
            <input type="button" name="newGame" value="New Game" onclick="dealer()" class="button" />
        </aside>
    </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.type = "hidden";` ?

Comment: Why `document.getElementById("dealer2").value = "Hidden";` instead of `document.getElementById("dealer2").type = "hidden";` ?

Comment: @Kimura Have you tried my answer below? I tested it and works without any problem...

Comment: "How to make X (dis)appear when the Y is Z'd" is a very common question on SO.  Have you searched here?

Comment: Note also that if you're ever going to do anything serious in JS you should learn to use [`element.addEventListener(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than `onclick="function"`

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr

Set the [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute using [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Use [.removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to reverse the setting of the attribute:

```
function dealer() {
    //...set dealer1, dealer2
    //hide the element
    document.getElementById("dealer2").setAttribute("hidden", "true");   
 }

function stand() {
    //show the element
    document.getElementById("dealer2").removeAttribute("hidden");
```

> *Is there a clean way to go about this?*

Yes, there are multiple. See the explanations below for a few common techniques.

#### Hidden Attribute

One approach is to set the [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute using [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Use [.removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to reverse the setting of the attribute:

```
function dealer() {
    //...set dealer1, dealer2
    //hide the element
    document.getElementById("dealer2").setAttribute("hidden", "true");   
 }

function stand() {
    //show the element
    document.getElementById("dealer2").removeAttribute("hidden");
```

There are varying opinions as to which approach is *better*. Refer to the [comments on this blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-hidden#comments), as well as answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20503034/1575353).

Also note that because the button labeled *stand* has the *name* attribute set, there is a reference to it in the DOM via `window.stand`. Because of this, the function *stand()* is being replaced with an object pointing to that element. One way to workaround this is to rename the element, like *standButton*:

```
<input type="button" name="standButton" value="Stand" onclick="stand()" class="button" />
```

```js
var dealer1;
var dealer2;
var player;

function dealer() {
  dealer1 = document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.random() * 11 + 1;
  document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.floor(dealer1);

  dealer2 = document.getElementById("dealer2").value = Math.random() * 11 + 1;
  dealer2 = Math.floor(dealer2);
  document.getElementById("dealer2").setAttribute("hidden", "true");

  player = document.getElementById("player").value = Math.random() * 21 + 2;
  document.getElementById("player").value = Math.floor(player);
}

function stand() {
  document.getElementById("dealer2").removeAttribute("hidden");
}

function dealCard() {

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

section {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #007929;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #000 2px;
}

header {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 10px;
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.cards {
  background-color: #63dd8d;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #009900;
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  clear: both;
  margin: bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Simple Blackjack</h1>
</header>
<form>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Dealer Cards:</td>
        <td><input id="dealer1" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer1" size="5" disabled="true" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="dealer2" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer2" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Your Card Total:</td>
        <td><input id="player" class="cards" type="text" name="player" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <aside>
    <input type="button" name="deal" value="Deal Card" onclick="dealCard()" class="button" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" name="standButton" value="Stand" onclick="stand()" class="button" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" name="newGame" value="New Game" onclick="dealer()" class="button" />
  </aside>
</form>
```

#### Hidden Input type

Also, as @rayon suggested in a comment, the [*type*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type) attribute could be changed from **text** to **hidden**.

> <sub>hidden: A control that is not displayed but whose value is submitted to the server.</sub><sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type)</sup>

```
function dealer() {
    //...set dealer1, dealer2
    //set type to hidden to hide the element
    document.getElementById("dealer2").type = "hidden";

}

function stand() {
    //set type to text to display it as normal
    document.getElementById("dealer2").type = "text";
```

```js
var dealer1;
var dealer2;
var player;

function dealer() {
  dealer1 = document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.random() * 11 + 1;
  document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.floor(dealer1);

  dealer2 = document.getElementById("dealer2").value = Math.random() * 11 + 1;
  dealer2 = Math.floor(dealer2);
  document.getElementById("dealer2").type = "hidden";

  player = document.getElementById("player").value = Math.random() * 21 + 2;
  document.getElementById("player").value = Math.floor(player);
}

function stand() {
  document.getElementById("dealer2").type = "text";
}

function dealCard() {

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

section {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #007929;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #000 2px;
}

header {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 10px;
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.cards {
  background-color: #63dd8d;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #009900;
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  clear: both;
  margin: bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Simple Blackjack</h1>
</header>
<form>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Dealer Cards:</td>
        <td><input id="dealer1" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer1" size="5" disabled="true" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="dealer2" class="cards" type="hidden" name="dealer2" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Your Card Total:</td>
        <td><input id="player" class="cards" type="text" name="player" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <aside>
    <input type="button" name="deal" value="Deal Card" onclick="dealCard()" class="button" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" name="standButton" value="Stand" onclick="stand()" class="button" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" name="newGame" value="New Game" onclick="dealer()" class="button" />
  </aside>
</form>
```

#### style (including CSS)

Another approach is to update element'style. Multiple styles can be used - e.g.  [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) can be to *none* using [.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style):

```
function dealer() {
    //...set dealer1, dealer2
    document.getElementById("dealer2").style.display = "none";
```

Then to show the element (when the button labeled *stand* is clicked), set that display style to a value other than *none* (e.g. a blank string, *inline*, etc).

```
 function stand() {
    document.getElementById("dealer2").style.display = "";
 }
```

See this demonstrated in the snippet below:

```js
var dealer1;
var dealer2;
var player;

function dealer() {
  dealer1 = document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.random() * 11 + 1;
  document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.floor(dealer1);

  dealer2 = document.getElementById("dealer2").value = Math.random() * 11 + 1;
  dealer2 = Math.floor(dealer2);
  document.getElementById("dealer2").style.display = "none";

  player = document.getElementById("player").value = Math.random() * 21 + 2;
  document.getElementById("player").value = Math.floor(player);
}

function stand() {
  document.getElementById("dealer2").style.display = "inline";
}

function dealCard() {

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

section {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #007929;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #000 2px;
}

header {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 10px;
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.cards {
  background-color: #63dd8d;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #009900;
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  clear: both;
  margin: bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Simple Blackjack</h1>
</header>
<form>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Dealer Cards:</td>
        <td><input id="dealer1" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer1" size="5" disabled="true" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="dealer2" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer2" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Your Card Total:</td>
        <td><input id="player" class="cards" type="text" name="player" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <aside>
    <input type="button" name="deal" value="Deal Card" onclick="dealCard()" class="button" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" name="standButton" value="Stand" onclick="stand()" class="button" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" name="newGame" value="New Game" onclick="dealer()" class="button" />
  </aside>
</form>
```

Or the [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) could be set to *hidden* in order to hide the element, and then set to *visible*  to show it.

```
function dealer() {
    //...set dealer1, dealer2
    document.getElementById("dealer2").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function stand() {
   document.getElementById("dealer2").style.visibility = "visible";
```

CSS classes could also be utilized combined with the above techniques. For example, the following css rule could be added:

```
#dealer2.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then use that class style rule by adding the class with [classList.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) and [classList.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods):

```
function dealer() {
    //...set dealer1, dealer2
    document.getElementById("dealer2").classList.add("hidden");
}

function stand() {
    document.getElementById("dealer2").classList.remove("visible");
```

```js
var dealer1;
var dealer2;
var player;

function dealer() {
  dealer1 = document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.random() * 11 + 1;
  document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.floor(dealer1);

  dealer2 = document.getElementById("dealer2").value = Math.random() * 11 + 1;
  dealer2 = Math.floor(dealer2);
  document.getElementById("dealer2").classList.add("hidden");

  player = document.getElementById("player").value = Math.random() * 21 + 2;
  document.getElementById("player").value = Math.floor(player);
}

function stand() {
  document.getElementById("dealer2").classList.remove("hidden");;
}

function dealCard() {

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

section {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #007929;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #000 2px;
}

header {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 10px;
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.cards {
  background-color: #63dd8d;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #009900;
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  clear: both;
  margin: bottom: 15px;
}

#dealer2.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Simple Blackjack</h1>
</header>
<form>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Dealer Cards:</td>
        <td><input id="dealer1" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer1" size="5" disabled="true" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="dealer2" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer2" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Your Card Total:</td>
        <td><input id="player" class="cards" type="text" name="player" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <aside>
    <input type="button" name="deal" value="Deal Card" onclick="dealCard()" class="button" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" name="standButton" value="Stand" onclick="stand()" class="button" /><br><br>
    <input type="button" name="newGame" value="New Game" onclick="dealer()" class="button" />
  </aside>
</form>
```

There are other techniques that will also accomplish the same requirement. Some javascript libraries (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) have wrappers for the techniques described above (e.g. jQuery's [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-type)</sub>

Comment: Yet another way is to set or toggle a class on the element. Start with `#dealer2 { visibility:hidden; }` and `#dealer2.revealed { visibility: visible; }` and just add the class `revealed` when the dealer shows the cards.

Comment: Good call, @Stephen P. I have incorporated the _visibility_ style into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be fetched using `jQuery` as shown below:

```
<input type="button" name="dealer2" value="Dealer2" style="display: none !important;" />

<input type="button" name="stand" value="Stand" onclick="stand()" class="button" />
  
<script>      
    function stand() {
        $("#dealer2").show();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide something with `javascript`:

```
document.getElementById("hello").style.display = 'none';
```

To show it again with `javascript`:

```
document.getElementById("hello").style.display = 'block';
```

Or you could just use `JQuery` instead.

Comment: As your last statement is `document.getElementById("hello").setAttribute('hidden', 'false');`, it should be visible element right ?

Comment: `hidden` attribute will hide an element with any/no value. all you need is `<span hidden></span>`

Comment: I think `hidden` is better because it works without having to take into account the correct `display` property value.  `none` vs. `block` is one case, but what about `inline` or `inline-block` or the now more common flex types?  You have to fetch the current property then set to `none`, then _restore_ not just set to `block`. _hidden_ bypasses all that. [Here's your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zbo1z7d/3/), more complete and interactive. Note `removeAttribute('hidden')` vs. `setAttribute('hidden', false)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use another name for `function stand()`
because name duplicated in `<input type="button" name="stand" value="Stand" onclick="stand()" class="button" />`

just use another name

To use Native javascript to change disabled attribute use `document.getElementById("dealer2").disabled = false;`

```js
var dealer1;
var dealer2;
var player;

function dealer() {
  dealer1 = document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.random() * 11 + 1;
  document.getElementById("dealer1").value = Math.floor(dealer1);

  dealer2 = document.getElementById("dealer2").value = Math.random() * 11 + 1;
  dealer2 = Math.floor(dealer2);
  document.getElementById("dealer2").value = "Hidden";

  player = document.getElementById("player").value = Math.random() * 21 + 2;
  document.getElementById("player").value = Math.floor(player);
}

function stnd() {
  document.getElementById("dealer2").disabled = false;
  dealer2 = document.getElementById("dealer2").value = "Changed";
}

function dealCard() {

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background: url("cards.jpg");
}

section {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #007929;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #000 2px;
}

header {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: url("cards.jpg");
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 10px;
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.cards {
  background-color: #63dd8d;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #009900;
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  clear: both;
  margin: bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Blackjack</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <header>
      <h1>Simple Blackjack</h1>
    </header>
    <form>
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Dealer Cards:</td>
            <td><input id="dealer1" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer1" size="5" disabled="true" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="dealer2" class="cards" type="text" name="dealer2" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Your Card Total:</td>
            <td><input id="player" class="cards" type="text" name="player" size="5" disabled="true" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <input type="button" name="deal" value="Deal Card" onclick="dealCard()" class="button" /><br><br>
        <input type="button" name="stand" value="Stand" onclick="stnd()" class="button" /><br><br>
        <input type="button" name="newGame" value="New Game" onclick="dealer()" class="button" />
      </aside>
    </form>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery you can do this:

```
$('input').click(function() {
   if ($('input').val() === "show") {
      $('#name').show('700');
      $('input').val("hide");
   } else{
      $('#name').hide('700');
      $('input').val("show");
   };
});
```

`#name` is `id` of your element. :D